# Arduino and reading from multiple USB connections

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm sending up a high-altitude balloon with an onboard [Mighty Ohm Geiger Counter](https://mightyohm.com/blog/products/geiger-counter/) and some other sensors, all of which will be managed by an R Pi B+. I'll collect and store the data with the R Pi; all of that's fine.

In order to track and recover it, I'm using the HABDuino shield on an Arduino. It uses the APRS system and sends back short messages, giving the altitude, internal temp, my callsign, and coordinates. I'd like to add the Geiger counter's data to that, but I'll need to get it from the R Pi.

Currently, I'm using an FTDI Friend to connect the Gieger counter to the R Pi, and getting the data from the serial port. I see [here](http://www.seeedstudio.com/recipe/166-basic-pi-lt-gt-arduino-communication-over-usb.html) that I can connect the Arduino and Pi vai USB, but... since there's already a USB connection to the Gieger counter, will there be a conflict? Is that something that I can work around?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the point of having multiple connections to the same arduino? Just choose one, or the other.

Comment: Have you tried using a hub?

Comment: There would be two USB connections to the PI, rather than the Arduino. I can't use just the Pi because I need the hardware (it's an Arduino shield) for the tracking, and I can't use just the Arduino because the tracking shield takes up all of the resources.

Comment: What sort of hub?

Comment: Ummm... USB hub?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about the Pi, not the Arduino.

Comment: Note you can also connect the Arduino to the pi's hardware serial UART, though if you are running your Arduino at 5v you will need level translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FTDI should be showing up as `/dev/ttyUSB0` on the Pi.

If you connect an Arduino as well it will show up as `/dev/ttyACM0`.

If you don't have enough USB sockets then just add a USB hub.